# How to access serial number of iPhone using a Windows Application (Any Language)

Tags: iphone, serial-number

Basically I want to grab the serial number from an iphone. On windows when you click properties on the phone, you can look at the serial number. I have tried using different libraries for node and java that use libusb but I cannot seem to pull the serial number. Are there any libraries that already have this functionality or code that can let me easily pull the serial number (preferably something that uses a library like libusb so I can use it on linux)

Answer (score 0):

This library will get you there.

https://github.com/0xFireball/MK.MobileDevice